# Using dates for page numbers in iBook Author?

Tags: books, epub

Is there a way (XSL?) to use iBooks Author (or to edit the underlying HTML) so that the page numbers are dates?

The value (for me) is an easy to navigate calendar with documents as separate pages easy to get to.

I realize a reasonable alternative is Notability or something like it.